# Convergence in topological space, coordinate-wise convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, product-space

Let $(X_j,\tau _j), j\in I$ and $(Z:=\prod_{j\in I},\tau ^\times)$ be topological spaces.

> Let, for some sequence $z_n\in Z, n\in\mathbb{N}$
>   $$\forall j\in I\left (\pi _j(z_n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \pi _j(z)\right )\quad (X_j,\tau _j) $$ where $z\in Z$. 
>   Show that $z_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}z\quad (Z,\tau _j)$. $\pi _j:Z\to X_j, j\in I$ is the projection mapping.
>   Show that the implication doesn't hold for $\tau ^\square$.

Essentially, if we let $z_n = (z_j^n)_{j\in I}, n\in\mathbb{N}$ and we have the given premise, is it true that coordinate-wise convergence is sufficient for convergence, at least for $\tau ^\times$?

Define $x_n\to x$ in some topological space $(X,\tau)$ if for every open neighborhood (NH) $U\in\tau$ of $x$, there exists index $N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t for every $n>N$, $x_n\in U$.

By assumption, we have $\pi _j(z_n) = z_j^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}z_j=\pi _j(z)$. Letting $j\in I$, for every open NH $V_j\in\tau _j$ of $z_j$, exists index $N_j\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n>N_j$ implying $z_j^n\in V_j$.

This means I can put together $z := (z_j)_{j\in I}$, but where would I use the fact that I'm operating w.r.t $\tau ^\times$?

As a counter-example, why the implication doesn't hold for $\tau ^\square$, one is invited to look at $(Z := \prod_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{R},\tau ^\square)$ with $z^n = (\underbrace{0,0,\ldots ,0}_{n-1}, n, n,\ldots),n\in\mathbb{N}$. from which it  seems that for every $j\in I$ $z_j^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$. Yet it's not sufficient for $z^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0 =: z$?

---

Drafting space.  Assume $I$ infinite
Basis of product topology: $\mathfrak{B}^\times := \left\lbrace \prod_{j\in I}U_j : u_j\in\tau _j, U_j=X_j \mbox{ for almost all }j\in I\right\rbrace$.
Basis of box topology: $\mathfrak{B}^\square := \{\prod_{j\in I}U_j : U_j\in\tau _j\}$

Basis of neighborhood: $\mathfrak{B}_x := \{B\in\mathfrak{B} : x\in B\}$.

Comment: The product topology is precisely the topology of coordinatewise convergence. To see why the condition works for the product topology but not for the box topology, recall what the difference between those topologies is. A neighbourhood base of $z$ in the product topology is given by the family […], a neighbourhood basis in the box topology is given by the family […].

Comment: @DanielFischer Unfortnately, I haven't the neighborhood basis description. I know that the product topology has basis elements of the form $\prod _{j\in I}U_j, U_j\in\tau _j$ where $U_j=X_j$ for almost all indices $j\in I$ (i.e $U_j$ is a proper subset of $X_j$ for finitely many $j\in I$). I don't understand how to bring that into play here :/

Comment: You can get a neighbourhood basis from that. Take the above basis $\mathscr{B}$, and let $\mathscr{B}(x) = \{ V \in \mathscr{B} : x \in V\}$. That is a neighbourhood basis of $x$. Do the analogous for the box topology. Try to describe these neighbourhood bases in words. Look at the difference between the descriptions.

Comment: @DanielFischer If I take a neighborhood basis element $B$ of $x$ w.r.t $\tau ^\times$, all I immediately see is that $B = \prod_{j\in I}U_j$ where $U_j\subsetneq X_j$ for finitely many $j\in I$. I can also see that $\tau ^\times\subset\tau ^\square$, but I can't understand the significance of it.

Comment: Okay. Now rename $x$ to $z$, and look at the sequence $(z_n)$. When do we have $z_n \in B$?

Comment: @DanielFischer $z_n = (z_j^n)_{j\in I}$ so $$\forall j\in I, z_j^n\in U_j $$

Comment: And for which $j$ is that an actual condition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49249/discussion-between-alvin-lepik-and-daniel-fischer).

Comment: The statement in the box could be cleaned up. For example, it should not be "for some $z\in Z$, but for the $z$ that appears before that. That confusion seems relevant, because you later write that you can put together the $z$, you should not need to, as it is already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed for the product topology $\tau^\times$ we have that coordinate-wise convergence is necessary and sufficient for convergence, while for the box topology $\tau^\square$ pointwise convergence is necessary (as the projections are continuous), but not sufficient.

The example of the sequence $z^n \in Z= (\prod_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}, \tau^\square)$, where $(z^n)_i = 0$ for $i < n$ and $(z^n)_i = n$ for $i > n$, is a fine example of this. For each fixed coordinate $m$, the sequence $(z^n)_m$ consists of $1,2,3,$ for the first $m$ terms, and $0$ after the $m$-th term. So every coordinate sequence is eventually $0$ (We can take $N= m$ for every neighbourhood of $0$ in that coordinate) and thus convergent to $0$.
But the neighbourhood $\prod_{j \in \mathbb{N}} (-1,1)_j$ in the box topology contains no $z^n$ at all, as $(z^n)_n =  n \notin (-1,1)$ for every $n$. So there is a neighbourhood of $0$ that does not contain a tail of the sequence so the sequence $(z^n)_n$ does not converge to the all $0$ sequence.

If we have that $(z^n)_j$ converges to some $z_j$ for every $j \in J$, and we have the product topology, then $(z^n)$ does converge to $z := (z_j)_j$. We only have to consider basic open neighbourhoods for convergence so take any $U = \prod_j U_j$ where every $U_j$ is open in $X_j$ containing $z_j$, and  we have a finite subset $I \subseteq J$ such that $U_j = X_j$ for $j \notin I$. This means we only hav finitely many constrained coordinates that we have to get the tails of the $x^n$ into:

For every $i \in I$ we pick $N_i$ such that for all $n > N_i$ we know that $(z^n)_i \in U_i$ by convergence in  this coordinate $i$.
Now take $N = \max(N_i, i \in I)$ which is a maximum of finitely many $N_i$, so finite as well. And if $n >N$, consider any coordinate $j$. If $j \in I$ then  $(z^n)_j \in U_j$ as $n > N \geq N_j$. If $j \notin I$, $(z^n)_j \in U_j = X_j$ is trivial (no constraint by the form of the type of neighbourhood). 
In all cases $(z^n)_j \in U_j$, so $z^n \in U$ for $n > N$ as required. This shows convergence of the $z^n$ to $z$.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the product topology, for every $j\in I$ and for every $B_z^j\in\mathfrak{B}_z^j\subset\tau _j$ there exists $N_j\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t for every $n>N_j$ implies $z_j^n\in B_z^j$. We have $B_z = \prod _{j\in I}U_j$ s.t $z\in U_j, j\in I$ and $U_j=X_j$ for almost all $j\in I$, hence for almost all $j\in I$ $z_j^n\in U_j\in\tau _j$ holds trivially.
For some finite $J\subset I$ we can find $\max_{j\in J} N_j =:N$.

Now, letting $(z_j)_{j\in I} =:z$ and $B_z\in\tau ^\times$, for every $n>N$, by construction, $z^n\in B_z$.

As for the counter-example. It would seem that coordinate-wise convergence to $0$ is sufficient for convergence to the zero-family, but no. By choice of $(z_n)$, for every $j\in I$ and for every $B_z^j\in\mathfrak{B}_z^j$ there is some $N_j\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t for every $n>N_j$ the coordinate sequence $(z_j^n)_{n=1}^\infty$ becomes stationary ($0$). However, these $N_j$ are clearly not bounded from above, hence by fixing $B_0\in\mathfrak{B}_0\subset\tau ^\square$, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we can always find $N>n$ satisfying $z^N\notin B_0$.